# Qt get File directory based on directory content

Tags: qt, qt4, qfile, qdir

I have few directorates and one file *.txt under one Directory A, Directory path is in QString

```
say c:/A/1/2/3/4 
    c:B/C/A/1/2/3/4/5/6
```

In my code I have only the full path, now I want to get the directory until A(name of A can change anytime) based on the file *.txt

inshort:- I want to parse all directory and get the directory until the place where *.txt present  from right to left

Comment: QDir dd(FilePath);
    QFileInfo pathFile(dd, "*.cnm");
    QString FilePath1  =  pathFile.path();
    qDebug() << FilePath1;

Comment: It is returning the same directory structure

Comment: For clarity, I think you should add expected output to the question. What if there are more than one directories having name `A`, e.g. `c:/B/C/A/1/2/3/4/A/B/C`? Which one is the expected output, `c:/B/C/A/` or `c:/B/C/A/1/2/3/4/A/`?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to get the string of the file path to A? Ex. If the file path was:

```
C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/file.txt
```

you want to get:

```
C:/Users
```

If so, all you have to do is find the second index location of "/". You could do something like this:

```
QString filePath = "C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/file.txt";
int index = filePath.indexOf("/");
index = filePath.indexOf("/",index+1);
QString shortenedPath = filePath.mid(0,index);
```

This should give you:

```
C:/Users/
```

If that isn't what you meant, then sorry for the long response.

Comment: I think in this case `A` in question is equal to `Desktop` in your answer. So, what the OP wants is to extract `C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/1/2/3` to `C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/`, `C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/X/Y/Z`  to `C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/`...

Comment: THanks for giving your time to give response